# MongoDB : select * from tablename

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and need to query a table for all fields.

So I have my code as mentioned below:

```
dataset = db.collection.find({})
for d in dataset:
     print d
```

Output:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('570be40a30b147fbba6f523b'), u'type': u'min_hits', u'value': u'100'}
{u'data': [u'remote', u'temprary', u'ipnodes'], u'_id': ObjectId('570be47d30b147fbba6f523c'), u'type': u'box_list'}
```

How can I get the values of columns

> min_hits and box_list

I tried the below way

```
 print d['min_hits']
```

but I get below  error:

```
    print d['min_hits']
KeyError: 'min_hits'
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should have just queried them separately using [`find_one()`](http://go.collection.Collection.find_one):

```
min_hits = db.collection.find_one({"type": "min_hits"})["value"]
box_list = db.collection.find_one({"type": "box_list"})["data"]
```

Or, you may also meant to get the `type` and `value` or `data`:

```
dataset = db.collection.find({})
for d in dataset:
     data_type = d["type"]
     data_value = d.get("value", d.get("data", "No value or data set"))

     print(data_type, data_value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed example and clarification